# Shortcut key for 2 columns in a text box

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am looking for a shortcut key for columns in text boxes. I know that there is probably not one and that I would have to create it, but I don't know what you would call it in the shortcut menu.

I also know that I can go to text frame options to change the columns, but I want to click one button and have two columns. Is this possible. I use two or three columns A LOT! I would love to have a shortcut key for this.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I love keyboard shortcuts, but not everyone does. While it is definitely not as "one-click" as @Scott's answer, I still feel it is extremely efficient.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will bring up the `Text Frame Options`. Conveniently, the current number of columns is selected by default. Now you can just type the number of columns you want (such as <kbd>3</kbd>) and press <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>. No mouse interaction needed at all!

Comment: .. could have swore I read a comment with that somewhere... :)

Comment: Gosh, sorry @Scott, I just looked at your answer, and didn't even read your comments. I'm not a seasoned enough SE user to know what is appropriate at this point - should I delete my answer since it is kind of a duplicate? I'm more than happy to...

Comment: Oh no.. it's fine. My comment here was entirely tongue-in-cheek. :) Leave your answer.. it is ultimately correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the control bar.....

[image]

The up arrow button would constitute 1 click.

Comment: That's how we all do it... It's just irritating to be able to do anything with a keystroke and then having to grab the mouse to make 2 columns. Thanks for the image though! People will understand what I am talking about now. All my Google searches point towards the drop down menu right to the right of what you highlighted.

Comment: The drop down menu controls spanning, which is not the same as columns. I don't believe there is a shortcut for columns.. and I don't think you can set one. I, personally, use Command-B, hit a number, hit Enter. No need for the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no shortcut available, not even a custom one (that I can find, in the program or online)

This means that your only other alternative is to find or write a script that will increase the number of columns for you and then assign that script to a keyboard shortcut.

Otherwise you will need to continue to adjust this setting manually.